# How to split a large request object that contains many properties of which one of them is a huge list of values

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-core, serilog

Excuse me right off the bat. I am sort of new.

I have an object that contains few properties of which one of the property in that itself is a List. Now, we do not know how big the list of values in the input payload would be like (It could be 1000, it could be 100,000). We are logging this request payload before we process.

We use `_logger.Verbose ("Some String...", {object});`

When we log, the log file (We use Serilog) saves it as a notepad file with huge values, in JSON format.

Now, when the input is too big, the logger tries to log but fails and retries many times due to big payload.

I am looking for a way to split or do some looping and split and store or something. I dont know how to do in C# code. I tried googling and researched a lot but futile. I found SKIP and TASK methods of Lambda but unsure how to use.

Code below:In this case, imagine, "Model" is like 1000, or 100,1000 it could be anything. I am just looking for a loop logic in C# to divide to a decent number and process.

```
public class Make
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Category { get; set;}
    public List<Model> Models { get;set;}
}

public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string County { get; set;}
    public string Submodel { get; set;}
}

public ProcessCars ( Make object)
{
    _logger.Verbose ("Some String...", {object});`
    // Processing///
    //.....//
}
```

Comment: Just add an `if` before logging.

Comment: How is the logger failing? Serilog's standard file sink won't retry anything if logging fails - it sounds like something else might be going on, here. In any case, using `File.WriteAllText(...someTempFile...)` and then logging the filename, rather than its contents, might get you out of trouble in the short-term?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt: I am not sure how to do it, could you please help me with the C# code for that

Answer (score 0):

I understand the purpose of yours is to view or debug the values of your list.

If I were you, I would ask myself a few questions

Do I need to write all values? Why can't I filter first before logging? 
What's the purpose of writing to a text file, when you can log to database? Serilog support DB logging. 
Is it a best practice to log large values to a text file?

Comment: Sorry, I need to write all values, they are CRITICAL business domain models, no filtering needed coz all values are terribly important. I can not log to database, 5 years code, can not be changed by me in all 100,000 places and 10,000 projects. I am not hired for that and no time or priority but to serve the business. Its not VALUES in text file. These are request payloads, for any debug or such investigation purposes if something went wrong for any customer